# Incorrect results for year,month grouping for mysql count

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue with incorrect counts for a query which is as follows:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), '%M') AS month,
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS year, count(*) AS count FROM table1 WHERE
result LIKE '%created%' GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)),
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) DESC;

+-----------+------+-------+
| month     | year | count |
+-----------+------+-------+
| September | 2011 |     1 |
| December  | 2013 |   393 |
| November  | 2013 |    70 |
| September | 2014 |   233 |
| August    | 2014 |   739 |
| July      | 2014 |   691 |
| June      | 2014 |   618 |
| May       | 2014 |   120 |
| March     | 2014 |   272 |
| February  | 2014 |   528 |
| January   | 2014 |   607 |
+-----------+------+-------+
11 rows in set (0.40 sec)
```

However, when I check my work by using another syntax I get different results:

```
mysql> select count(*) from table1 where result like '%created%' and
timestamp >= unix_timestamp('2014-07-01') and timestamp <= unix_timestamp('2014-07-31');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      662 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.39 sec)
```

What is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: You don't have a `group by` in your second query, so mysql "collapses" the entire result set down to a single row. This is expected/normal behavior for mysql. most other DBs would abort and complain about using an aggregate function with no matching group-by clause.

Comment: @MarcB, his problem is not a single row but he is selecting the month july. First result of july gives a different number than the second result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second query use < unix_timestamp('2014-08-01'). I think you filter out everything that happened after 2014-07-31 00:00:00 am. There are still 24 hours in that day that shouldn't be filtered.

Comment: ahh yes because mysql will use time of 00:00:00 and you are missing an entire day.

Comment: exactly. please tag the answer as satisfying if so.